# Register certain events on client machine and notify to another C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Please don't get confuse yourself with the title of this question, I don't know what is the exact technical term of what I want to accomplish :). My requirement may be little strange and I already implemented it but I need some best practice/method to do it properly.

Here is my situation.

I am developing a client system monitoring windows application (Tracking software in client side and monitoring software in my system). I have many systems connected to a LAN and I have a monitoring system. If any certain actions happen on client system, I will get notified. I cannot use any databases in my network so what I am doing is, Since my system is also connected to LAN I shared one folder in my system. Whenever some actions happens in client system, Tracking software will create a file containing event to the shared folder in my system. The monitoring software uses a timer which will continuously check for any new files in the shared folder on a certain interval(15 Minutes). If any file found, monitoring system will know some event has happened and will show the event.

But the problem I will get notified only after 15 minutes. Also is I don't think this is the best way. There may be some good and best methods. Is there any way like registering event directly to my Monitoring application from client machine?

Please NOTE: I cannot use any Database for this purpose.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You can't just use a Sqlite or flat file database and sockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) - it provides real time notification and can be used exactly as you describe.

You would not require a database (but remember if your server isn't running you will miss events - this may or may not be acceptable).

Comment: I have a signalr application using a windows 8 app, talking to a wpf app - signalr isn't just for the web :-)

Comment: Then I withdraw my previous objection :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).  This will monitor directories and raise events.  IME, it works well, but can fail with large amounts of traffic.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect candidate for MSMQ (MS Message Queue) and [Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms703197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Create an MSMQ that all your Tracking Softwares can write to. Then have an MSMQ trigger (perhaps connecting to a front-end through WCF/named pipes) to display an alert in your Monitoring Software

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [WCF Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms731082.aspx).

Here is two links that can help you:

[wcf-tutorial-events-and-callbacks](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-events-and-callbacks)

[wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication)